# Changing to an SD Card

Tags: insufficient-memory

Because my internal storage didn't have enough space for new applications and updates I decided to change where applications were being installed to my SD card.

I used the adb commands and a message informed me that I changed to the SD card. However when tried I was unable to download applications due to insufficient space which means that my primary memory is still my internal memory.

How can I change to the SD storage?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy 2 7.0, OS 4.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Just switching the default install location does not free up storage. If you follow up to the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), you will find the explanation:

> First thing you should check when encountering this problem is how much internal storage is left on your device (space on sdcards, internal or external, is completely irrelevant to this problem). As a general thumb rule, **you need at least 25 MB free**

So regardless where apps are to be installed: *Google Play* first needs to download them, and stores them in `/data/local` before installing them. This is in *internal* storage, hence it will check there for "sufficient space".

For things to do, again the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) is a good starting point, and should be sufficient to solve your issue (basically, you need to free up some space, e.g. by moving some apps to SD or deleting some you no longer need). If that still didn't solve the issue, please indicate (and update your question to note what you tried, what the outcome was, and where you're stuck).